# How can I get the CDF for a random variable with given PDF as $p(t)= 2e^{-2t}, t \ge 0$?

Tags: probability-distributions

> Suppose the PDF for th random variable $Y$ is
>   $$p(t)= 2e^{-2t}, t \ge 0$$
>   Can someone show me the CDF for $Y$?

I want to see the answer to this example so I can apply the same concept to other problems but have never encountered a PDF in this format. The bounds are what I'm really not sure about.

Comment: $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)\,dt$$

Comment: So the bounds would still begin at -inf regardless of the value of t?

Comment: You just need to set the lower limit to be less than or equal to any positive value of you PDF. In this case, $-\infty$ or $0$ would be the same (assuming $p(t) = 0$ for negative $t$).

Comment: Yes the lower bound is always $-\infty$, only, in your case, $$f_X(t)=2e^{-2t}\mathbf 1_{t>0}$$ hence the part $(-\infty,0)$ of the integral yields $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read the pdf for $Y$ as
$$
f(y)=\begin{cases}
p(y),&y\geq0\\
0,&y<0
\end{cases}
$$

Now, you can apply the definition of cdf:
$$
F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^yf(y)\ dy
$$
and finish the calculation.